# Postfix unable to send mail from mydomain only

Tags: debian, dns, postfix, domain

My domain DNS is served by the domain registrar.

I am able to send mail successfully from any address with postfix but not from mydomain.com

From this machine - I only want to be able to send mail.

I know it must have something to do with DNS and my domain registrar.

When postfix main.cf configuration has

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

I am getting:

```
status=bounced (mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself)
```

When I add mydomain.com to the mydestination (as suggested on the internet)

```
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```

I get

```
status=bounced (unknown user: )
```

Now I know I am missing something very obvious here, I just can't figure what that is.

Comment: can you post the output of `postconf -n` and the log lines generated by postfix to help you better.